# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space with rascal code

Tags: memory-management, rascal

I try to manipulate big strings in rascal and get constantly the following error:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space(internal error).

I changed the following parameters in the eclipse.ini file:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-Xms256m 
-Xmx1024m
```

But that changes nothing.

The code looks like this:

```
public str removeBB(str file){
while(contains(file, "aB")){
    index1 = findFirst(file, "aB");
    index2 = (findFirst(file, "Ba") + 2);

    subString1 = substring(file, 0, index1);
    subString2 = substring(file, index2);

    file = subString1 + subString2;
}

return file;
}
```

How can i prevent this error? Are there ways to write that code so that it is more memory efficient?

Comment: Hey, you didn't change the occurrence of `BB`, which makes the while loop infinitely looping.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see immediately why this code is thrashing memory, maybe because it finds index2 smaller than index1 in your example string?

But anyway, I would write something like using a regular expression and visit, instead of using indexOf:

`visit (file) {
  case /aB.*Ba/ => ""
}`

Also, string slicing has a nicer syntax to use, instead of substring:

`rascal>"asdlhfasldfhslf"[5..8]
str: "fas"`

Comment: perhaps this way you also loose the memory trashing behavior. Could you post an example string on which the memory goes sky high?